# How can I move a specific set of user data from one MySQL database to another with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, transfer

I have two MySQL databases with similar sets of data, both on the same server. I need to grab select fields from a given table in database X and move them into given fields of a table in database Y. The table names are different, but field names are the same except for a prefix on database Y.

The database should be moved based on a unique username that exists on both ends. So I would get the data for username A, then find username A in database Y, and copy the data from the select fields for that user.

Any direction or advice would be much appreciated. This by the way would be a process to run as needed, not something that needs to continuously run. Using PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.

Comment: you can do cross-database queries. `insert into db1.foo ... select * from db2.bar where ...` As long as the user account you're logged in as has the appropriate rights on both dbs, it's totally transparent.

Comment: each database has a different set of login credentials. I'd have two connections going. I think this is the part that has me stuck.

Comment: then you need to round-trip the data through your client. e.g. `while(fetch row from db1) { insert data into db2 }`

Comment: You'd need to select all data, stuff it into an array, and then connect to the new DB. Then, traverse the array and insert the records.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO database1.customer (
  id
  fname,
  etc
) 
SELECT 
  id
  fname,
  etc
FROM
  database2.customer
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I handle the connection to both databases that have different login credentials?

Comment: Good question! As long as you connect to MYSQL with a user that has permissions on BOTH databases, this will work, because you are explicitly identifying each database in the query.

Comment: `$link1 = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database1"); mysqli_select_db($link1, "database1"); $link2 = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database2"); mysqli_select_db($link2, "database2"); 

INSERT INTO $link2.table_name ( 
  id,
  fname,
  address,
  email,
  etc
)
SELECT (
  id,
  fname,
  address,
  email,
  etc )
FROM 
  $link1.table_name;`

Something like this???

Comment: I think the piece I still need is a connecting field. To clarify, I'm not simply moving data from one place to another, I'm UPDATING data. In both tables, there is a field already in place that matches. So I need to update all entries in table X with data from table Y WHERE field A (from table X) is the same as field B (from table Y). Sorry that I didn't explain this better initially. Getting close I think, just don't know how to make this extra step. Thanks again!